# Convert a HTML string into a xlsx file to download (angularjs)

Tags: html, angularjs, xlsx

I'm looking to convert my HTML string into a downloadable xlsx file.
Assuming this HTML table string :

```
const htmlString = '<style>
td{font-weight: bold;}
</style>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>'
```

I'd like to download it as an Excel file (.xlsx).

I've seen libraries like SheetJS, XLSX but it seems like none of them can convert a html string, it's more about json and other stuff. Maybe I'm wrong ? Do you know a library that can do this?

I tried the File Saver library to download a file, that works well.

Comment: Checkout this demo for HTML table https://sheetjs.com/demos/table.html and its using sheetjs, sheetjs is your best choice.